# How do I regex to match the following - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following I want to validate against, how do I create a regex to check this?

I want to validate

```
1-ABCD
```

Such that I have a single digit followed by a hyphen and then 4 letters (case insensitive)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following statement

```
"1-ABCD".match(/\d-\w{4}/);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
"1-ABCD".match(/^\d\-\w{4}$/)
```

Same as above one, additionally we need to add the start and end of string